# How to project the BEV to the front view?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-projection

I have a picture of the BEV and camera pose.

How do I turn it into a front view of the blue vehicle in the picture?

[BEV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl6C9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Only based on the info you give, it's not possible to get a "proper" ego vehicle front view.

Detail:
To change the camera view angle for an image, you need to know at least these information: camera intrinsics (if the image is with distortion, you also need to see the dist coeff), the extrinsic/rotation from the current view to another view.

Then you can do the view transform by using homography matrix

[calculation method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2mIE.png)

It can give you result like this

[homography matrix view transform example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9jEA.jpg)

You can refer to [this opencv example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#homography_course)

But! A very important part is that all the result we mentioned above can't let you handle translation (In my opinion it's what your request need to handle). Because the image doesn't contain any depth information.

But I guess you are using a simulator, so you might be able to get these info. (kind of a cheat method)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).